# Document-literal-bare webservice in Weblogic

Tags: java, xml, web-services, weblogic

I need to create a webservice, that accepts *any* xml in the request soap:Body element and replies with *any* xml in the respond soap:Body. The appropriate WS operation style is (in my opinion) "document-literal-bare". I expect that the resulting WSDL message would look something like this:

```
<s0:message name="process">
    <s0:part type="xs:any"/>
</s0:message>
```

How am I to do it?

**Details**:

In Weblogic 10.3, I have written:

```
@WebService(.....)
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use=SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle=ParameterStyle.BARE)
public class BackEndSimulatorWS {

    @WebMethod
    public XmlObject process(XmlObject request) {
        .....
    }
}
```

However the Eclipse protests with

```
(The "process" method) must be doc/literal/wrapped when binding wildcards to any.
```

I understand that the WS must be able to determine which method to execute, so I tried to annotate the method with

```
@Webmethod(action="simulation")
```

but this didn't help. When I replace the org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject parameter and response type with org.w3c.dom.Document, the error disappears, but the resulting WSDL messages are not general, they are of the {java:org.w3c.dom}:Document type.

Any help will be appreciated.